Github Action .Net Build Time: Windows vs MacOS vs Ubuntu
I have a Github action that builds .Net project for:



OS
Build Time




win-x64
1 min 45 s


osx-x64
43 s


linux-x64
48 s



name: Build and Release

on:
  workflow_dispatch: 

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [windows-latest, macos-latest, ubuntu-latest]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.0.x'

      - name: Restore dependencies
        run: dotnet restore src

      - name: Publish project
        run: |
          dotnet publish ./src/MyProject -c Release -r ${{ matrix.os == 'windows-latest' && 'win-x64' || matrix.os == 'macos-latest' && 'osx-x64' || 'linux-x64'}} --self-contained -o ./publish/${{ matrix.os }} /p:Version=${{ env.VERSION }}
        env:
          DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: 1

I observed a slight variety between Linux and OSX, but Windows would constantly at least double the time and lag far behind in:

setting up .Net
restoring dependencies
building/publishing the project


I assume ubuntu has .Net 8 installed already, and therefore it skips the Setup .NET and has 0 secs there. But MacOS taking 7s vs Windows taking 17s to setup .Net? How is that?
Then restoring and Building is similar for Linux and MacOS, but Windows is far behind, how is that?
Is there a way to optimize the Windows scenario?

Does it mean that compiling with Rider on Linux should take 2x less time than compiling with Rider on Windows?
